# Sending email via JWebServices for Exchange and JAVA

Tags: exchange-server-2007

```
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Body;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.ItemInfoResponse;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Mailbox;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Message;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.Service;
import com.independentsoft.exchange.ServiceException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Service service = new Service("https://myserver/ews/Exchange.asmx", "user", "password");

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setSubject("Test");
            message.setBody(new Body("Body text"));
            message.getToRecipients().add(new Mailbox("John@mydomain.com"));
            message.getCcRecipients().add(new Mailbox("Mark@mydomain.com"));

            ItemInfoResponse response = service.send(message);
        }
        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getXmlMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hello! I tried to send an email, but did not work. 
I'ved used a valid user and password, at  message.getToRecipients I used my yahoo email address.
At output on eclipse this is my result. Where is my mistake ?

```
JWebServices for Exchange 2.0 evaluation version, www.independentsoft.com.
myserver
null
myserver
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.createItemImplementation(Unknown Source)
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.send(Unknown Source)
    at Example.main(Example.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myserver
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.independentsoft.exchange.Service.a(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "myserver" with real name of your Exchange server.

Comment: print out "null, null"

Answer (score 0):

try to AutoDiscover your service url first:
[Sample here](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/office365.html)